# XmlPullParserException: Unexpected token

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser

I'm trying to parse an XML with `XmlPullParser`, that starts like this:

```
<ArrayOfApplications xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

but I got this error:

> .xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT @1:2 in java.io.BufferedReader@415af968)

I read about it but didn't got anything useful. I think the problem is around the `xmlns:xsd` and `xmlns:xsi`.

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Could you solve your problem? If my answer was correct, you should accept it so others can see it.

Comment: the XML contains the header. The problem was that the streamreader didnt know what was the encoding and messsed at the namespace... I used com.google.gdata.util.io.base.UnicodeReader.UnicodeReader(InputStream arg0, String arg1) where i could define the encode format...
BTW thanks for your time ;)